# transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo does not wake the extension delegate

Tags: apple-watch, widgetkit, watchconnectivity

When calling WCSession.default.transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo , the watch extension does not wake (init is never called) when the watch application is inactive.

It does work fine when the watch application is in the foreground. And the didReceiveUserInfo is being called.

WidgetKit developer mode is set, so that remainingComplicationUserInfoTransfers is not an issue.

using watchOS 9.5 and SwiftUI / WidgetKit complications.

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be an issue with Apple. More details in this thread:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/735352

> Apple responded that this appears to be a bug on their side, but no
> ETA for a fix was given. We are keeping our fingers crossed